# Android server concept confusion. How to connect TCP chat app on different networks

Tags: android, sockets, networking, tcp

I followed a chat app tutorial that connects devices using TCP sockets.

For simplicity, I split the app into 2, so that one is the server and the other is the client.

The app works fine when I am using the same wifi network, but it does not when one of my devices jumps into a different network.

This is where I get confused on the concepts.

Because they are different networks, I cannot use the local IP as I have been doing. I did find using the public IP is possible, but I'm still new to coding so am not sure if that's the right method. Should I look into VPS? Or GCM?

Do I need to rewrite my app such that I have 2 clients (that talk to each other) and that they go through the server with a static IP (like a middle man)? But then I get confused because in that case, Client would start first and then talk to Server. But I always thought Server was to start first and wait for an accepting socket??

Not sure if this is the right place to ask these questions, I'm just really confused on the concepts. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For socket programming in your apps, the only info you need is IP address and port number. After switching to another network, the only modification to your source code is IP address.

When devices are not in the same local area network, you need routers to locate each other, in theory. If you don't own control to routers, using a public and static IP is the right solution. The app acting as a server should have this static IP and should always be alive, and listen to connections. The app acting as a client starts later and connects to the server with its IP address and the port number you've defined.

Normally when you get access to Internet, you get a public IP from your ISP, and it keeps static if you keep online, in most cases. So just find out the IP address on your server, and connect to this IP address from your client app. If your internet access is gained from a wireless router, you should set up port forwarding on the router, and use the IP address of this router at client.