# TCP Chat not working in different networks

Tags: c++, networking, tcp, ip

I coded a TCP/IP Chat Server/Client in C/C++ that works perfectly in my local network and with several clients connected to it.  It does not work when the Server is in a different network to the client. I coded time ago the same tool in Python and the same happened.

Is there any way of solving this? Without port forwarding, that is the most common solution.

I could only find this: [Android server concept confusion. How to connect TCP chat app on different networks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31708605/android-server-concept-confusion-how-to-connect-tcp-chat-app-on-different-netwo) but I could not understand it.

NOTE: I have just find a sample program (server) that works when it is on a different network; http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1891/Beginning-Winsock-Programming-Simple-TCP-server

Comment: what is exactly `C/C++` language, if I may ask?

Comment: Which interface(s) do you bind to for the server? Have you made sure no firewall rules between the networks stop your communication?

Comment: Does your server on other network has a public ip?

Comment: 1. C/C++ Means C and C++ ?

Comment: 2.There is not firewall, antivirus etc.. running, and ports are opened

Comment: 3. Yes, i tried using the client pointing to the server public IP adress. No result.

Comment: On one system, can you `ping` the other system? Also, there is no "C and C++" language, either you're programming in C, or you are programming in C++.

Comment: Yes, i can ping the other system IP. From my point of view, there is C and C++ language, for example if in a code I use malloc() and free() (C) and new() and delete() (C++), I believe that.

Comment: Your point of view is incorrect wrt C/C++. If using C++ just use new/delete. Saves a lot of headaches

Comment: Simple rule: Unless your code is _fully_ compatible (i.e. with all recommendations **and** sematics) with C, it is C++ only.

Comment: Not to be impatient or anything, but again, what interfaces are you binding the server socket on? Can you please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of both the server and the client?

Comment: @PedroJavierFernández You answered the wrong question. He asked if one system could ping the other system. And that answer is no. While one system can ping the other system's IP, it's only because the IP is assigned to the router, not the system.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg the server socket is binded using a TCP socket on the 'localhost' in port 9999

Comment: @DavidSchwartz right. I could ping the public IP, which in fact is the same public IP for al devices connected to my home router. (In that case, I don't know how to specifically ping that device)

Comment: If you bind to localhost (instead of all interfaces) then the server is only reachable from localhost.

Comment: @joachimpileborg what value do I have to pass to bind to do that? I didn't know that. Thanks

Comment: Just about all tutorials and beginners guides will show you how to use `INADDR_ANY`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In local network addresses of devices doesn't change offently. Yo can reach the computer by only defining the local address. On the other hand, if you want to communicate with a device in different network yoou should know its public IP and should define a routing to the port.

If you have a server with static IP or known IP you can reach it. You can store the IP addresses of clients dynamically in this server. Write a program that inform the IP of host computer to the server. In that way, you can store the IP addresses even they change oftenly.

Comment: Thanks :) But, lets say that I only want to test it with a friend: He starts the server and he gives me his current public IP(and the port). My idea is to be able to connect to him, just with the client and the information he provided me.

Answer (score 2):

You have three choices:

1) NAT penetration. Both devices simultaneously attempt to exchange data with each other, tricking each person's router into thinking that it's replying. For this to work, you each need each other's public IP address and if you need any features from TCP, you need to implement them yourself.

2) Public rendezvous server. Both devices automatically connect to a server on an unNATed network. The server knows the public IP address of every client that connects to it, so it can route your data to the client with the correct public IP.

3) Some combination of 1 and 2. Here, a public server is used to facilitate NAT penetration and eliminate the need for manual coordination. Your friend registers with the public server and the public server tells him your public IP address and facilitates NAT penetration.